# C# - Settings.cs was not generated when I merged my code to another branch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, application-settings

I am using TFS, with visual studio 2010.
I added a setting to the application settings, in the settings.setting file and everything worked fine.
When merging my code to another branch, when compiling, I got an error that "Settings.cs" was not found. What did I miss? What was I suppose to do so that it would be automatically generated? 
Of course after I manually added it to the project it compiled, but I need it to work not only on my computer.

Thanks

Comment: You should check the changeset, did you check in that the file was added in the first place?

Comment: That file wasn't checked in, but I read that it is supposed to be automatically generated.

Comment: Note that VS 2010 drops out of mainstream support in July. You should consider updating to a modern version of VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Settings Build Action as Content and Copy to Output Directory As Copy Always.

Comment: in Settings.settings or Setting.cs?